# Finding the number in the 2019th decimal place of $(5+\sqrt{26})^{2019}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Any ideas?
Also is there a way to do it for arbitrary $n$?

I was given this problem in an algebra olympiad preparation course.

Comment: Have you tried using a binomial series to approximate $\sqrt{26}$?

Comment: No. How would it be done?

Comment: What do you mean by 'is there a way to do it for arbitrary $n$'? Also, is this part of an ongoing contest?

Comment: Are you doing it using a computer?

Comment: No. It is supposed to be done by hand.

Comment: Ohk.. Looks tricky to get just the 2019th digit. Hope somebody posts a clever method:)

Comment: Thank you for editing the title: in the previous version it seemed like you wanted to find all of the $2019$ digits of the number.

Comment: According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.%C3%9710%5E10+%2B+IntegerPart%28%285+%2B+sqrt%2826%29%29%5E2019%29&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22Math%22%7D), the $2019$th digit is $4$.

Comment: I don't know if this is useful but here is a nice recurrence relation you can play with:  
 $$a^n+b^n = (a^{n-1}+b^{n-1})(a+b) - ab(a^{n-2}+b^{n-2})$$
Here $a=5+\sqrt{26}$, $b=5-\sqrt{26}$ are the roots of quadratic $x^2-10x-1$, and notice that $(5-\sqrt{26})^n$ approaches $0$ for large $n$

Comment: Which country are you from? In addition, have you studied recurrence relations like in pooja's comment before?

Comment: I am from Latvia and yes I have studied  recurrence relations.

Comment: Niks, if at all possible please give a link to your training site. You see, the appearance of 2019 makes it possible that this could be from *an on-going contest*. We have a rule not to allow such questions (many of us are involved in organizing contests, and want to prevent possible cheating). I believe you in that this is more likely a training problem (as opposed to from a running contest) given that the solution is "standard", and has appeared many times.

Comment: There isn't a training site. We were given this as homework for olympiad algebra in pdf format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sequence $f_n = (5+\sqrt{26})^n + (5-\sqrt{26})^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
It is easy to check it satisfies a recurrence relation:
$$f_{n+2} - 10 f_{n+1}  - f_{n} = 0$$
Since $f_0 = 2, f_1 = 10$ are integers, by inductions, all $f_n$ are integers.

For $n = 2019$, this leads to

$$(5+\sqrt{26})^{2019} = f_{2019} + (\sqrt{26}-5)^{2019}
$$

Since $\sqrt{26} - 5 \approx 0.0990195 < 0.1$, we obtain

$$\left\{(5+\sqrt{26})^{2019} \right\} = 
(\sqrt{26}-5)^{2019} \in (0,10^{-2019})$$
As a result, the $2019^{th}$ decimal place (the $2019^{th}$ digit after the decimal point) for $(5+\sqrt{26})^{2019}$ is '$0$'.

Comment: The idea is repeated often, and is a duplicate. But +1 for bringing sanity to a thread that was heading in a wrong direction.